# Detail in standard measure theory I cannot seem to obtain

Tags: integration, measure-theory, proof-explanation, simple-functions

There is a standard result in measure/integration theory which I just cannot seem to obtain.

If $f \colon X \to \mathbb{C}$ is measurable ($X$ is any measurable space), there exist simple measurable functions $\phi_k \colon X \to \mathbb{C}$ such that $\phi_k \to f$ pointwise and all $|\phi_k| \le |f|$. This is fine.

*However*, it is often claimed that the $\phi_k$ can be taken such that also $|\phi_k| \le |\phi_{k+1}|$ for all $k$. (See for instance Folland's *Real Analysis*, Proposition 2.10.) This I cannot seem to obtain, at least not with the simplicitly for which it is claimed to follow.

It is typically stated that this can be obtained as follows (e.g., Folland): Write $f = u + iv = u^+ - u^- + i(v^+ - v^-)$, the standard decomposition into positive and negative parts $u^\pm$ and $v^\pm$ for $u = \Re f$ and $v = \Im f$. Pick simple measurable functions $s_k^\pm$ and $t_k^\pm$ such that $0 \le s_k^\pm \uparrow u^\pm$ and $0 \le t_k^\pm \uparrow v^\pm$. Put
$$\phi_k := s_k^+ - s_k^- + i(t_k^+ - t_k^-).$$
The $\phi_k$ are simple measurable functions $X \to \mathbb{C}$, and clearly $\phi_k \to f$ pointwise. All good.

*At this point it is typically claimed that also $|\phi_k| \le |\phi_{k+1}|$ for all $k$, but how is this obtained in this exact setup? It appears standard wisdom is that $|\phi_k| = s_k^+ + s_k^- + t_k^+ + t_k^-$, from which it would follow easily indeed, but I am skeptical of this identity.*

Suppose for the moment that $f$ is real (but please address the complex case), so that $v = 0$, hence $t_k^\pm = 0$. Then $\phi_k = s_k^+ - s_k^-$, a difference of two positive functions. From this follows
$$|\phi_k| = \phi_k^+ + \phi_k^- \le s_k^+ + s_k^-,$$
but it is easy to cook up positive functions $s_k^\pm$ (below) for which the above inequality is strict, i.e., $|\phi_k| < s_k^+ + s_k^-$. Hence it cannot be the case that $|\phi_k| = s_k^+ + s_k^-$ in general; it appears to me a common pitfall is to confuse oneself from the identity $\phi_k = s_k^+ - s_k^-$ to believe that $s_k^\pm$ must be the positive and negative parts of $\phi_k$ (e.g., last computation [here](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Measurable_Function_is_Pointwise_Limit_of_Simple_Functions)), but this is not true unless there is a trick involved. What is this trick?

---

Example of strict inequality in a positive decomposition: Take $u := 1_{(-\infty, 1]}$ and $v := 1_{[-1, \infty)}$ on the real line. Take $f := u - v$. Then in general $f^+ \le u$ and $f^- \le v$, and in this case there holds $|f| = f^+ + f^- < u + v$.

---

I suppose I could salvage the proposition by working out at a detailed level, but the proposition is claimed to follow leisurely from the approximation of positive measurables, so surely there is a trick here I am missing?

Comment: There is an easy proof using polar form of $f$. Are you interested?

Comment: @geetha290krm Is it $f = \phi |f|$ for measurable $\phi$ of unit modulus, then pick simple $0 \le s_k \uparrow |f|$ and any complex simple measurable $\phi_k \to \phi$ of modulus $\le 1$ and form $s_k \phi_k$? If so, that one is clear. But it seems this sort of technique is not what Folland and other standard references are getting at; Folland explicitly suggests the approach I outline above…

Answer (score 0):

You need to also use the fact that these approximations are subordinate to the positive and negative parts of $u,v$. Here’s a more precise version of what I mean:

> **Lemma**
>
> Let $u:X\to[-\infty,\infty]$ be a given function and $u^+,u^-$ its positive, negative parts. Suppose $0\leq s_1\leq u^+$ and $0\leq s_2\leq u^-$ are given functions. Then, the subtraction $s:=s_1-s_2$ is a well-defined function $X\to [-\infty,\infty]$, with $s^+=s_1$ and $s^-=s_2$.

We cannot have $s_1(x)=s_2(x)=\infty$, because that would mean $u^+(x)=u^-(x)=\infty$, which is absurd (in fact if $u^+(x)>0$ that automatically implies $u^-(x)=0$, and vice-versa); hence the subtraction $s:=s_1-s_2$ is well-defined.

- Suppose $s(x)=0$. Then, $s_1(x)=s_2(x)$. If this common value is strictly positive, then $u^+(x)>0$ and $u^-(x)>0$, which as I said above is impossible by definition. Hence, $s_1(x)=s_2(x)=0$. So, $s^+(x):=\max(s(x),0)=\max(0,0)=0=s_1(x)$, and similarly, $s^-(x)=s_2(x)$.
- Suppose $s(x)>0$. Then, $s_1(x)>s_2(x)\geq 0$, which implies $u^+(x)>0$ and so $u^-(x)=0$ and hence $s_2(x)=0$. So, $s^+(x)=\max(s(x),0)=\max(s_1(x),0)=s_1(x)$, since it is positive; also we have $s^-(x)=-\min(s(x),0)=-\min(s_1(x),0)=-0=0=s_2(x)$.
- Suppose $s(x)<0$. Then, $s_2(x)>s_1(x)\geq 0$, and so $u^-(x)>0$, which implies $u^+(x)=0$, and thus $s_1(x)=0$, and so $s(x)=-s_2(x)$. It follows that $s^+(x)=0=s_1(x)$ and $s^-(x)=s_2(x)$.

This covers all the cases, so indeed $s^+=s_1$ and $s^-=s_2$.

---

Now, let $f:X\to\Bbb{C}$ be a given function, $f=u+iv=(u^+-u^-)+i(v^+-v^-)$ be its decomposition. Suppose we take any functions $0\leq s^+\leq u^+, 0\leq s^-\leq u^-, 0\leq t^+\leq v^+, 0\leq t^-\leq v^-$, and define $s=s^+-s^-$ and $t=t^+-t^-$ and $\phi=s+it$. By the previous lemma, these really are the positive and negative parts, so it’s not an abuse of notation. So, we have
\begin{align}
|\phi|&=\sqrt{s^2+t^2}=\sqrt{|s|^2+|t|^2}=\sqrt{(s^++s^-)^2+(t^++t^-)^2}.
\end{align}
Now, if you put a subscript $k$ everywhere, then obviously we have the increasing nature of everything.

Comment: Excellent, I suspected it had something to do with mutually singular support or subordination to other functions, but could not be bothered to identify your lemma.

Comment: P.S. My example on positive decompositions is not put forth to contradict the claim in Folland's proof. It is there to highlight that one cannot expect things to work out nicely unless one uses more assumptions, as identified in your lemma.

Comment: @Qeeko yes that’s what I meant to say: it is obvious that the expression of a function as the difference of two non-negative functions is not unique (even simpler is $0=1-1=0-0$ to show the non-uniqueness of the decomposition of the zero function), and indeed we need some extra assumptions. But ok, now we’re all in agreement.

Comment: My example is not even to the effect of demonstrating non-uniqueness; the point is that if $f = u - v$ for positive functions $u, v$, then $|f| = u + v$ might fail.

Comment: yes, and that failure essentially gives us non-uniqueness

Comment: Yes, although not its raison d’être.